# What method would make this code more efficient or proper?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a program that collects information based on the radio buttons that are checked, as well as a checkbox.

```
Private Sub calculateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateBtn.Click
    Dim TypeCost As Integer
    Dim ColorCost As Integer
    Dim Foldable As Integer

    If standardRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 99
    End If
    If deluxRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 129
    End If
    If premiumRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 179
    End If

    If blueRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 0
    End If
    If redRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 10
    End If
    If pinkRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 15
    End If

    If foldableCheckBox.Checked() Then
        Foldable = 25
    Else
        Foldable = 0
    End If

    Dim Price As String = TypeCost + ColorCost + Foldable

    priceTextBox.Text() = "$" & Price
End Sub
```

I have a strong feeling that this code can be simplified, but I just can't seem to think of what it is. My friend suggested Enumerations and Arrays, but I don't think those would work. Would they?

I have been searching around for a question similar to this for a while now.

I would also like to point out that the type radio buttons and the color radio buttons are in separate group boxes, so they function separately. Making it impossible for more than one type or color to be selected at the same time.

---

I have uptade the code to:

```
If standardRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 99
    ElseIf deluxRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 129
    ElseIf premiumRbtn.Checked() Then
        TypeCost = 179
    End If

    If blueRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 0
    ElseIf redRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 10
    ElseIf pinkRbtn.Checked() Then
        ColorCost = 15
    End If

    If foldableCheckBox.Checked() Then
        Foldable = 25
    Else
        Foldable = 0
    End If
```

I knew there was something extremely simply I would be able to do to sort of get rid of some of the repetitiveness. Thank you, phatfingers.

If there's any other ideas anyone would like to throw out, I would love to hear them. But this solution is good enough for me.

Comment: Terribly sorry about that. It is vb.net.

Comment: You could use ElseIf on your TypeCost and ColorCost determination.

Comment: I've changed it to ElseIf. Thank you. That was mainly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I simply went from using a bunch of if statements to "ElseIf". The updated code is in the original thread. :) - Thank you to phatfingers for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dropdown, which would probably be the lowest effort solution and allow you to dynamically add new options without rewriting anything.

You can then just fetch the value of the selected item.

https://forums.asp.net/t/988528.aspx?Dynamically+adding+items+in+DropDownList

So something like:

```
Private Sub OnFormLoad() //I forgot the exact name of the load event of the form and what it looks like

    typeDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Standard", "99"))
    typeDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Premium", "129"))
    typeDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Deluxe", "179"))

    colorDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Blue", "0"))
    colorDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Red", "10"))
    colorDropDown.Items.Add(New ListItem("Pink", "15"))
End Sub

Private Sub calculateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateBtn.Click
     Dim Price as String = typeDropDown.SelectedValue + _
         colorDropDown.SelectedValue + _
         iif(foldableCheckBox.Checked(), 25, 0)
     priceTextBox.Text() = "$" & Price
End Sub
```

Comment: I would use this if I could, but I am required to use radiobuttons for the circumstances.

Thank you very much for the response though.